# Microsoft Dynamics SOAP RetrieveMultiple not returning TotalRecordCount

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm working with the SOAP API for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 and for the most part everything is working, but when I'm trying to count the number of total contacts in the database (or for particular queries), it's not respecting the TotalRecordCount=true flag.

Here is the SOAP request that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <CrmAuthenticationToken xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">
            ...
        </CrmAuthenticationToken>
    </soap:Header>

    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveMultiple xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">
            <query xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query" xsi:type="q1:QueryExpression">
                <q1:EntityName>contact</q1:EntityName>
                <q1:Distinct>true</q1:Distinct>
                <q1:PageInfo>
                    <q1:ReturnTotalRecordCount>true</q1:ReturnTotalRecordCount>
                    <q1:PageNumber>1</q1:PageNumber>
                    <q1:Count>1</q1:Count>
                </q1:PageInfo>
            </query>
        </RetrieveMultiple>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But the response that I'm getting back still contains the following:

```
TotalRecordCount="-1" TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded="0"
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong / missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any results in your query? E.g. do you recieve the contact records?

I'm pretty sure I've had a problem with this type of approach in the past (using the paging information to get a count).

In any case you will probably have better luck with peforming a FetchXml query with an aggregate function (Im assuming your executing this Soap from JavaScript).

Jamie Miley has a good example of how to do this: http://mileyja.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/aggregation-count-max-min-etc-and.html

There is a really good designer for FetchXml here: http://www.stunnware.com/